# Which database has more coverage for window functions MySQL 8.0 or PostgreSQL 10?

Tags: postgresql-10, mysql-8.0

I am interested in computing statistics over moving window ranges

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you looking for, but regarding window functions both MySQL 8.0 and PostgreSQL 10 implement the same set of them. They both support `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses.

```
CUME_DIST()
DENSE_RANK()
FIRST_VALUE()
LAG()
LAST_VALUE()
LEAD()
NTH_VALUE()
NTILE()
PERCENT_RANK()
RANK()
ROW_NUMBER()
```

**[Click here for PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-window.html)**

**[Click here for MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html)**

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL 11 takes the lead again by implementing the lesser seen window frame unit `GROUPS` (in addition to `ROWS` and `RANGE`), as well as by adding support for the (in my opinion arcane) window frame exclusion clause.

An example of what's possible in PostgreSQL 11, but not MySQL 8 is this:

```sql
WITH t(v) AS (
  VALUES (1), (1), (3), (5), (5), (5), (6)
)
SELECT
  v,
  array_agg(v) OVER (o GROUPS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING EXCLUDE CURRENT ROW) AS current,
  array_agg(v) OVER (o GROUPS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING EXCLUDE GROUP) AS group,
  array_agg(v) OVER (o GROUPS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING EXCLUDE TIES) AS ties,
  array_agg(v) OVER (o GROUPS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING EXCLUDE NO OTHERS) AS no_others
FROM t
WINDOW o AS (ORDER BY v)
```

Yielding:

```
v |current     |group       |ties          |no_others     |
--|------------|------------|--------------|--------------|
1 |{1,3}       |{3}         |{1,3}         |{1,1,3}       |
1 |{1,3}       |{3}         |{1,3}         |{1,1,3}       |
3 |{1,1,5,5,5} |{1,1,5,5,5} |{1,1,3,5,5,5} |{1,1,3,5,5,5} |
5 |{3,5,5,6}   |{3,6}       |{3,5,6}       |{3,5,5,5,6}   |
5 |{3,5,5,6}   |{3,6}       |{3,5,6}       |{3,5,5,5,6}   |
5 |{3,5,5,6}   |{3,6}       |{3,5,6}       |{3,5,5,5,6}   |
6 |{5,5,5}     |{5,5,5}     |{5,5,5,6}     |{5,5,5,6}     |
```

[I've blogged about these PostgreSQL features more in detail here](https://blog.jooq.org/2018/07/05/postgresql-11s-support-for-sql-standard-groups-and-exclude-window-function-clauses/).